# HTML <base> in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is

```
<base href="http://google.com" /> 
<img src="/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" />
```

supported in chrome? It works fine in firefox.

Specifically, relative image links aren't resolving to the base url.

It is for:

http://webnumbr.com/create?url=http://google.com

Tested in latest of OSX and Windows Chrome (4.0.249.78)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error.  Works fine for me on Chrome 4.0.249.78.

Comment: The image shows correctly on the page I linked to?

Comment: Didn't look at that (at work), but I made a test page with just html, head and body tags plus your sample code above and it worked fine. (Repost because I just learned about comment notification)

Comment: On this computer, the image isn't shown indeed (in Chrome 4.0.249.78). Must be a Chrome-specific problem, because it renders fine in Safari 4.0.4, both on Windows XP. But what kind of a website is this? There is some unreadable code in it that might ruin the paths, or something like that, but I'm unable to trace bugs in this.

Comment: It simply fetches any given URL, and renders it to the browser so a user can extract any number that they want by just clicking on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And to answer your question about the `<base>` tag being supported in Chrome: it is. I created a simple HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <base href="http://google.com"> 
    <title>Testing base-tag</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <img src="/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

which is rendered correctly.

**EDIT: PROBLEM PROBABLY DISCOVERED**

I searched the Chromium bugs page for [**"base tag"**](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=base+tag&colspec=ID+Stars+Pri+Area+Type+Status+Summary+Modified+Owner+Mstone+OS&x=mstone&y=area&cells=tiles) and found two (probably the same) bugs about your problem, i.e. issue **[25090](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25090)** and **[32134](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32134)**.

I suggest you file a comment in one of those (after deleting [the forbidden end tag of <base>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4)) and hope this problem is resolved soon.

**EDIT 2:** I made another test case and commented in [**this bug report**](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32134#c2).

**EDIT 3:** Bug seems to be resolved after [upgrading to Chrome 4.0.249.89](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32134#c3).

Comment: Ok, then do you have any idea why my page doesn't render the image (in the Chrome version posted?)

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the image url, according to Developer Tools, resolves to "chrome://devtools/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" instead of "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif".

Comment: If I click "Inspect" and go to "Properties" and "HTMLImageElement" it lists the src as "http://webnumbr.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" and the baseURI as "http://webnumbr.com/create?url=http://google.com". But for your test page, it is correctly setting the base to be "http://google.com".

Comment: problem is 100% solved in .89. I guess I don't have to hack around it after all! Thank you so much for your help, here's an upvote :)